# Is there one word or phrase that best describes the emotion of happiness when winning?

Tags: phrases, synonyms

Or potentially a word that is used in another language to describe this feeling?

Answer (score 1):

**Exultation** = the act of exulting; lively or triumphant joy, as over success or victory ([Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/misspelling?term=exulation&s=t)).

**Elation** = a feeling or state of great joy or pride; exultant gladness; high spirits ([Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/elation)).

**Triumph** = the joy or exultation of victory or success ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/triumph)).

**Festivity** = An experience or expression of celebratory feeling, merriment, gaiety ([Wictionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/festivity)).

Comment: ok.............

Comment: +1 for triumph. The other feelings could be felt without winning something.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways. For example, "over the moon" is a common expression in the UK.

https://www.theanswerbank.co.uk/Adverts/Question1540549.html